# Linq Join Not Equal

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have 3 classes:

```
public class HoteAvail
{
    public int HotelID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

}

public class Room
{
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
}

public class DAL
{

    public static List<HoteAvail> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<HoteAvail>()
        {

           new  HoteAvail{HotelID=1,Name="Taj",Rooms=new List<Room>(){new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="Deliux"}}},
           new  HoteAvail{HotelID=2,Name="x",Rooms=new List<Room>(){new Room{RoomID=2,RoomName="dd"},new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="qq"}}},
           new  HoteAvail{HotelID=3,Name="y",Rooms=new List<Room>(){new Room{RoomID=3,RoomName="yy"},new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="rr"}}},

        };
    }

    public static List<HoteAvail> GetAllII()
    {
        return new List<HoteAvail>()
        {

           new  HoteAvail{HotelID=1,Name="Taj",Rooms=new List<Room>(){new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="Deliux"},new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="pp"}}},
           new  HoteAvail{HotelID=4,Name="x",Rooms=new List<Room>(){new Room{RoomID=2,RoomName="dd"},new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="qq"}}},
           new  HoteAvail{HotelID=5,Name="y",Rooms=new List<Room>(){new Room{RoomID=3,RoomName="yy"},new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="rr"}}},

        };
    }
}
```

I want to join the values of DAL.GetAll() and DAL.GetAllII() and result should contain only  those values whose HotelID doesnot matches.

The final result set should be like :

```
new HoteAvail{HotelID=2,Name="x",Rooms=new List<Room>(){new Room{RoomID=2,RoomName="dd"},new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="qq"}}},
new HoteAvail{HotelID=3,Name="y",Rooms=new List<Room>(){new Room{RoomID=3,RoomName="yy"},new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="rr"}}},
new HoteAvail{HotelID=4,Name="x",Rooms=new List<Room>(){new Room{RoomID=2,RoomName="dd"},new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="qq"}}},
new  HoteAvail{HotelID=5,Name="y",Rooms=new List<Room>(){new Room{RoomID=3,RoomName="yy"},new Room{RoomID=1,RoomName="rr"}}}
```

I tried:

```
var groupBNames = new HashSet<string>(DAL.GetAll().Select(x => x.HotelID.ToString()));
var filteredEmployees = DAL.GetAllII().Where(x => !groupBNames.Contains(x.HotelID.ToString()));

var resultList = from a in DAL.GetAll()
where !(DAL.GetAllII().Any(HotelID => HotelID == a))
    select a;
```

But I am not getting any success. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<HoteAvail>`:

```
public class HoteAvailComparer: IEqualityComparer<HoteAvail>
{
    public bool Equals(HoteAvail x, HoteAvail y)
    {
        return x != null && y != null && x.HotelID == y.HotelID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(HoteAvail obj)
    {
        return obj.HotelID;
    }
}
```

that you can use for [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is efficient since it's using a set:

```
var resultList = DAL.GetAll().Except(DAL.GetAllII(), new HoteAvailComparer());
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", resultList.Select(h => h.HotelID))); // 2,3
```

**Update**

> It is giving me HotelId 2, 3 where as I want to join the values of
>   DAL.GetAll() and DAL.GetAllII() and result should contain only those
>   values whose HotelID doesnot matchesi.e. The result should have
>   HotelId 2,3,4,5

Then you need to use `Except` from both perspectives:

```
var hotelComparer = new HoteAvailComparer();
var all1 = DAL.GetAll();
var all2 = DAL.GetAllII();
var resultList = all1.Except(all2, hotelComparer).Concat(all2.Except(all1, hotelComparer));
```

The desired result 2,3,4,5:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", resultList.Select(h => h.HotelID)));
```

Of course you could also use `Concat` and `GroupBy`, but it's less efficient and maintainable:

```
resultList = all1.Concat(all2).GroupBy(h => h.HotelID)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

You can use the `IEqualityComparer<HoteAvail>` for many other LINQ methods like `GroupBy`+`Distinct`,`Join`,`Intersect` etc.

Comment: Tim , It is giving me HotelId 2, 3
where as I want to join the values of DAL.GetAll() and DAL.GetAllII() and result should contain only those values whose HotelID doesnot matchesi.e. The result should have HotelId 2,3,4,5

Comment: The result should have HotelId 2,3,4,5

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend doing 2 excepts using a custom IEqualityComparer. You can use [this method](http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-two/) to create the comparer:

```
// create a comparer to compare HotelAvail objects by hotelId
// see http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-two/
// for the implementation of EqualityComparers.Create, which is a nice shortcut
var comparer = EqualityComparers.Create<HoteAvail>(ha => ha.HotelId); // compare by hotelId

var results = 
    // first take all entries in GetAll() NOT IN GetAllII()
    DAL.GetAll().Except(DAL.GetAllII(), comparer)
        // then add all entries in GetAllII() NOT IN GetAll()
        .Concat(DAL.GetAllII()).Except(DAL.GetAll(), comparer);
```

Comment: What is `EqualityComparers`.

Comment: Comparer must be `var comparer = EqualityComparers.Create<HoteAvail>((l, r) => l.HotelId == r.HotelId);`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: the post I reference has 2 overloads of Create, one of which takes just a key selector function. That's the one I'm using here.